# NGINX Stream Push with FFMPEG - VPS 4-Core 8-GB Ram

Tags: nginx, ffmpeg, stream

Hallo Guys and a nice Weekend!

I try over Weeks to get my Stream not lagging but its happend every 6 second.

I run a Ubuntu 16.04 with this Tutorial installation:

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git

git clone https://github.com/Noxalus/Multi-Streaming-Server.git

And my Config File ist this one:
`

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;
 
error_log  logs/error.log  debug;
error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
error_log  logs/error.log  info;
pid        logs/nginx.pid;

 
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include             mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    sendfile            on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;

    server {
        listen          8080;
        server_name     localhost;

        # rtmp stat
        location /stat {
            rtmp_stat all;
            rtmp_stat_stylesheet stat.xsl;
        }
        location /stat.xsl {
            # you can move stat.xsl to a different location
            root html;
        }

        # rtmp control
        location /control {
            rtmp_control all;
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
    }
}
 
rtmp {
    server {
        listen 2321;
        chunk_size 8192;

        application h132333234 {
            live on;
            record off;
            
            allow publish all;

            exec ffmpeg -i rtmp://localhost/$app/$name -c:v libx264 -preset veryfast -c:a copy 
                -threads 3
                -c:v libx264
                -profile:v main
                -preset:v veryfast
                -level 4.2
                -b:v 2500k
                -bufsize 2500k
                -maxrate 2500k
                -s 1280x720 -r 30
                -g 120 -keyint_min 60 -x264opts "keyint=120:min-keyint=120:no-scenecut"
                -tune zerolatency
                -c:a copy
                -f flv rtmp://localhost/twitch/${name};
        }
        
        

        application twitch {
            live on;
            record off;
            
            allow publish 127.0.0.1;
            deny publish all;

            push rtmp://ber.contribute.live-video.net/app/live_key;
        }
    }
}
```

Its same if i use 1920x1080 with 60FPS or 1280x720 with 30 FPS

Also whene i go to baseline or ultrafast from preset. Can it be from the Input from 3840x2160?

Or use i the wrong ffmpeg Settins?

I need only to resize it to get the 2K Stream playable on twitch in lower quality.

When i Stream on the 3840x2160 with 18.000 KBits, Twitch make it ugly and not realy good to watsh.

Any other Options i can Try, other Software or should i use a second OBS Instance?

best reguards

Comment: You need higher bitrates. See [Twitch Video Encoding/Bitrates/And Stuff](https://stream.twitch.tv/encoding/) for recommended settings. No need to set `-profile:v main` or `-level 4.2`. Keyframe interval should be 2 seconds, so make `-g` or all of the keyint options 2x your `-r`. Consider removing `-threads 3` and letting the encoder choose the optimal value. You have `-c:v`, `-preset`, and `-c:a` options listed twice.

Comment: Thanks!

Will try it now and watsh if it works better!